# GAE Django cloudsql socket

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I'm trying to set up a django project on Google app engine but i can't seem to connect from my computer to the database to do things like syncdb and so on.

this is my configuration (Altered)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/something:else',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
    }
}
```

now the connection to the database works on the deployed app, but not when I'm running it from my end, the error I get is

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/something:else'
```

I'm running osx, I installed google cloud sdk as well app engine SDK obviously, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: do you have an IP address set for external access for your database?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood no I don't is it needed?

Comment: if you want to connect to it from something other then your GAE application then you do, yes, as I understand it. You will pay per minute it is active.

Comment: because when it uses the socket it will use oauth2 and it will seem to the database that the connection is coming from localhost, so if I go by this way I won't need to, at least that's what I understand from the django tutorial which doesn't mention about the external IP, but I did read that connection with socket need grant permission to localhost

Comment: well, I'm afraid I don't know anything about that. AFAIK for external access you need an IP. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will be along shortly :)

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to perform a syncdb ? Normally the 'manage.py syncdb' command should provide a link to open in your browser and get the oauth2 token.

Comment: @brian ya I get that error on every command I give, I don't get any browser windows or aything at all, I think it mostly just doesn't find the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't connect to it because your local environment won't recognize host `/cloudsql/something:else`, this is only be recognized on production environment.

You can follow these approach to make it working in dev and production environment.

## Using the same production Cloud SQL instance in both production and local

First, you have to go on the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com) to give access to your current ip.

### Give access to your current ip

1. Go to Cloud SQL console, click on your instance name.
2. Click "edit" button
3. in Assign IP Address, select "Assign IP Address"
4. in below "Authorized IP Address", add an IP address on your development computer.

### Database setting

And then use the setting as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '<your-database-password>',
        'HOST': '<your-database-ip>',
        'NAME': '<your-database-name>',
    }
}
```

## Use separate different databases for production and dev server

You can separate settings for production and local development server:

```
if os.getenv("SERVER_SOFTWARE", "").startswith("Google App Engine"):
    # production
    DATABASES = {
        # production database settings
    }
else:
    # local dev server
    DATABASES = {
        # local database settings
    }
```